# Casting NSManagedObjects and Strings with Core Data in Swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, core-data

I'm using the AddressBookUI framework to pull a contact out of the address book and insert their name and number(s) into a `UITableView` and CoreData.

I have/had the `UITableView` part working and am now lost as this is my first time using CoreData. I changed my `Array`s to `NSManagedObjects` and adjusting my code the way I thought I should have and when I select a contact am getting the error:

> Could not cast value of type '__NSCFType' (0x19456ccb8) to 'NSString'
>   (0x19482a768).

when attempted to cast them.

How do I get this cast properly to insert the content from `namesArray` and `numbersArray` into CoreData?

(CoreData has `PhoneCore` as entity and `name` and `number` as attributes/Strings.)

```
import UIKit
import AddressBookUI
import CoreData

class ViewController: UIViewController, ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet var contactsButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var phoneList: UITableView!
    var numbersArray = [NSManagedObject]()
    var namesArray = [NSManagedObject]()
    var phone = String()
    var name = String()
    //var CoreNumbers = [NSManagedObject]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    let personPicker: ABPeoplePickerNavigationController

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        personPicker = ABPeoplePickerNavigationController()
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        personPicker.peoplePickerDelegate = self
    }

    func peoplePickerNavigationControllerDidCancel(peoplePicker: ABPeoplePickerNavigationController!) {
        /* Mandatory */
    }

    func peoplePickerNavigationController(peoplePicker: ABPeoplePickerNavigationController!, didSelectPerson person: ABRecord!, property: ABPropertyID, identifier: ABMultiValueIdentifier) {
        /* A property in a person was picked */
    }


    @IBAction func performPickPerson(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.presentViewController(personPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    func peoplePickerNavigationController(peoplePicker: ABPeoplePickerNavigationController!, didSelectPerson person: ABRecordRef!) {
        /* Do we know which picker it is? */
        if peoplePicker != personPicker{
            return

        }


        /* Get all phone numbers this user has */
        let phones: ABMultiValueRef = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty).takeRetainedValue()
        let names: ABMultiValueRef = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty).takeRetainedValue()


        let countOfPhones = ABMultiValueGetCount(phones)

        for index in 0..<countOfPhones{

            phone = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, index).takeRetainedValue() as! String

            numbersArray.append(phones as! NSManagedObject)
            namesArray.append(names as! NSManagedObject)
            phoneList.reloadData()
            println(numbersArray)
            println(namesArray)
        }
    }

//UITableViewDataSource

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
    return numbersArray.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

    let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "test")
    let namesConstant = namesArray[indexPath.row]
    let numbersConstant = numbersArray[indexPath.row]

    cell.textLabel?.text = numbersConstant.valueForKey("name") as? String
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = namesConstant.valueForKey("number") as? String

    return cell
}
}
```

Comment: Which line(s) of code are causing that error? Also, where is your code that attempts to insert objects into Core Data?